# 16.04 Desktop wallpaper is broke after gnome 3 install

Tags: gnome, filesystem, desktop-background

I tried gnome 3, and after my desktop wallpaper is just black.

I've tried many fixes so far. There were other problems like my login screen was broken. Uninstalling gnome, and reinstalling ubuntu did fix the other problems, but the wallpaper still remains black.

My desktop icons do show. Someone has asked a question about both wallpaper, and icons, but this doesn't apply to my situation.

This command doesn't work:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

<s>I installed ubuntu-tweak-tool which didn't have the option that everyone says to change.</s>

The solution here [Ubuntu 16.04 wallpaper under black screen, after login (unity 7.4.0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775939/ubuntu-16-04-wallpaper-under-black-screen-after-login-unity-7-4-0) does not work.

What to do?

**Update:** Somewhere I read that setting desktop icons to off in ubuntu-tweak-tool can get the wallpaper back. I did this, and I now have my wallpaper back. But this is not how it worked before. I don't use the desktop as a "desk" with icons on it, but I would prefer it worked as it did before. At least with the ability to add folders/files to the desktop.

**Update 2:** Also my nautilus file browser looks different than it did before.

Comment: Did you select a solid color for your desktop, or actually choose a patterned wallpaper?

Comment: I selected an image. In fact I already had an image selected as wallpaper. I didn't change it. I just installed gnome3, and things got messed up along with the wallpaper.